# Innodb file format - Percona Server

Tags: mysql, percona, percona-server

I had my innodb file format changed from antelope to barracuda recently.

Is it safe to have both antelope and barracuda at the same time? I have my setup running properly now.

What issues I would face? Or should I change it back to antelope.